# Can we add Debug information to Logcat using ADB commands or any other means?

Tags: android, adb

I am running a script on an Android device and getting data from logcat. Is there anyway I can add debug statements to logcat in runtime using adb commands or any other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Android should redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null. You can for instance change this behaviour by redirect stdout/stderr to log with:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

more info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#viewingStd

Update:
From within your script, just use:

```
log -p i "your message"
```

to append the message to the log

Comment: @Ankur make sense?

Comment: So using this I can redirect logcat to my logfile? What I need is for example if I change camera settings via some script, I want to add a debug message in Logcat like 'Camera Setting Changed Now'.

Comment: Thanks It works!!Any links so that I can explore more on this?